# Solving an Ordinary Differential Equation 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential question:

$\displaystyle ydx-xdy=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dx$

My Attempt:

$\displaystyle (y-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dx=xdy$
$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(y-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{x}\\
\end{align}$$
Put y=vx
$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{(vx-\sqrt{x^2+x^2v^2})}{x}\\
\displaystyle v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=v-\sqrt{1+v^2}\\
\displaystyle x\frac{dv}{dx}=\sqrt{1+v^2}\\
\displaystyle \frac{dv}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}=\frac{dx}{x}\\
\displaystyle \frac{dv}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}=\frac{dx}{x}\\
\displaystyle Integrating, \; \sinh^{-1}v=\log x \\
\displaystyle Now, \; \sinh^{-1}v= \log(v+\sqrt{1+v^2}) \\
\displaystyle \log \left(\frac{y}{x}+\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}\right )=\log x \\
\displaystyle \log \left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right )-\log x=\log x \\
\displaystyle \log \left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right ) =2\log x \\
\displaystyle \log \left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right ) =\log x^2 \\
\end{align}$$

I am stuck here. The given solution is $\displaystyle y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=c $

Please help.

Comment: Add constants when you integrate, especially when you're solving differential equations (otherwise you don't get the most general possible solution).

Comment: You lost a minus sign somewhere, so that the logs do not cancel out as should. (Crossed with M. Vinay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a $-$ sign in the step where you cancelled out $v$. So in a later step you'll get $-\log x$ on the RHS, and that will get cancelled out with with one on the LHS. Then you'll get the correct answer.

$$\log\left(y + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right) - \log x = -\log x + C\\
\log\left(y + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right) = C\\
y + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = c$$